# What is a viable build for Teemo vs. Teemo?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently had trouble against an opposing Teemo. What build would work best to counter another Teemo?

Comment: Being new to the site I can't imagine you knowing this, but an "opinion" is not welcome on this site. I would suggest re-wording your question before it gets closed or downvoted.

Comment: nice of you to dislike :P

Comment: To add onto my previous comment, so more information would be very helpful. What were you building/what did your opponent build. Levels, skill picks, cs...etc.

Comment: I typically don't downvote new members, so wasn't me.

Comment: Without any additional information to go on, all I can suggest is to check these out: http://www.solomid.net/guide?champ=teemo&featured=1&submitted=0&sort=3

Comment: I shall go to yahoo answers with all this nonsense. I just wanted a straight answer

Comment: I reworked your question to better fit the site. hopefully it'll atleast survive a close vote.

Comment: Champion build questions unfortunately have been acceptable on the site

Comment: @Brian yes but asking straight up for an opinion usually isn't, nor is asking for the best build. These kinds of questions usually sit in the gray area so straying can put you in the red.

Comment: I really do not know the "restrictions" of this site. I am at school and by the sound of this I don't think I like this site. Is this site for "pros" or something?

Comment: This site tends to punish new members horribly. A number of members would rather put you down than help you, unfortunately. On the other hand you are expected to read the Meta before posting. The standard is pretty high, wouldnt go as far as to say professional.

Comment: If it makes you feel better my first three posts to this site over 2 years ago all got closed/deleted.

Comment: Sorry if your first impression wasn't a great one. First, you might want to check out [these](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [two](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) articles, just to get a feel for what sort of questions are a good fit for the site. Secondly, you might have discouraged anyone who was thinking about helping by sort of abrasively "calling out" an anonymous person for downvoting your question. Just my speculation. Your question already has been tweaked to make it a little less speculative, so you should be good to go now!

Answer (score 2):

Well, to actually answer your question...

In a Teemo vs Teemo matchup, you MUST build AP.  AD will come out ahead in a fight for the first couple of levels but after that AP is far superior (I'm talking this particular matchup).

Build high flat AP items asap.  You can't rely on autos with blinding dart.  You mainly focus on poking with higher damage from your blind and don't directly fight unless you will win the longer battle for sure.

If you are vs an AP teemo, start of Chalice so you can spam your Q quicker.  If you are vs an AD teemo, you can start of Zhonya's and/or chalice since teemo still does sufficient magic damage.  At some point from here you will want to get a Lliandry's and Rabadon's.  Also, somewhere in there mix in Sorc boots.

From this point on, you should focus your build mostly around what you need for the rest of the enemy team.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to a mirror matchup between two Teemos, the biggest problem is that you cannot know what the enemy Teemo plays in champion select (and unless you are playing a custom game you won't even know that there is an enemy Teemo). So you have to start with the runes.

Teemo is a rather aggressive laner and you should also try to play aggressive against an enemy Teemo. Since you usually don't know that you play against another Teemo you should take a mix of early aggression runes and a little bit of defense just to be safe in general. I recommend **Hybrid-Penetration red** (Good for early aggression and you don't drop off late), **Armor yellow** (almost always take these), **Magic resist blue** (Teemo does mainly magic damage) and **AP Quints** (For more damage) of which all are non-scaling. With these runes you are safe for a general matchup and against a Teemo, but if you know that you are playing against a Teemo you can also switch the armor for health. Note that these runes are for AP/Hybrid Teemo only. For masteries just go for a standard 21/9/0 skill tree. You can also play AD Teemo with a standard AD Carry rune page but I don't recommend playing it since Teemo scales too well with AP to be played as AD. Also you will most likely lose to an AP Teemo as AD Teemo.

When it comes to the Item build you should stick to your current playstyle (AP or AD). Just go a normal starting item either Dorans Blade if you are playing ad or Dorans Ring/Boots if you are playing AP. Boots can be really helpful since it makes chasing a lot easier if the enemy doesn't buy them first and you also will get 4 Healing potions which help a lot versus an harrassing lane opponent.

What you build next depends entirely on who dominates the lane. If you can dominate try to keep it up and go for an aggressive build. Buy a Haunting Guise next if you are AP, a Bilgewater Cutlass if you are AD or a Wits End if you are hybrid. Note however that you will have to keep the pressure up if you buy the aggressive Items.

If you are behind however you should focus on a more passive playstyle and you have to try to get back in the game through farm (if needed under the turret). You will need to buy damage (you will be useless otherwise) but you will also have to keep an eye on defensive stats. That means go for a Hexdrinker if you are AD, for a Chalice/Abyssal Scepter if you are AP or again for a Wits end if you are Hybrid. You can basically always build magic resistance against a Teemo since his strength lies in his early base damage which is purely AP. Once you lose to an AD teemo due to a lack of armor you definitely have lost your lane and it will be hard to regain an advantage over him without the help of your teammates or without him doing something incredibly stupid.

Comment: The only thing I disagree with is the option to go AD or AP.  If you are in a Teemo vs Teemo matchup you MUST go AP.  AP will ALWAYS beat AD Teemo in lane past like level 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Runes**

Starting off with the runes I would suggest you:

- **Greater Glyph of Ability Power** x9 - As an AP carry, glyphs offer the best boost to Ability Power. I choose the flat AP glyphs as I
  believe that both runes and masteries offer the best advantage in
  early game and lose their efficiency in late game.

*or*

- **Greater Glyph of Scaling Ability Power** x9 - If you'd like to build for a late game, I would recommend these instead. They become
  as effective as the Glyph of Potency at level 6 so you wont be
  sacrificing all that much.

*or*

- **Greater Glyph of Magic Resist x9** - For more survivability against heavy AP teams or mid lane.
- **Greater Seal of Attack Speed** x9 - Teemo and Attack Speed have both an on-screen and off-screen love affair. Both AD and AP Teemo
  benefit from attack speed in many ways. While AD Teemo benefits from
  faster auto-attack damange, AP Teemo benefits from faster on-hit due
  to our *Toxic Shot*.

*or*

- **Greater Seal of Armor** x9 - Teemo can play any lane decently. If you are running up top lane to take on that Darius, a bit of armor
  will make you feel a little more comfortable. Not recommended for mid
  lane.
- **Greater Mark of Magic Penetration** x9 - Marks offer the best magic/armour penetration. As an AP carry build, these are the best
  choice to nullify any early magic resist your opponents may have -
  like Teemo in our case.

*or*

- **Greater Mark of Attack Speed** x9 - Even more attack speed if you find that you don't need as much magic penetration.
- **Greater Quintessence of Movement Speed** x3 - Teemo is one of the faster champs due to the passive his *Move Quick* gives. These quints
  will only help you in evading any skill shot, any gank, and out of
  any sticky situation you can imagine with proper awareness.

*or*

- **Greater Quintessence of Ability Power** x3 - If you find that our *Move Quick* offers enough movement speed for you, feel free to pick these babies up for a huge bonus in our early game presence.

**Masteries**

*Offensive*

- **Summoner's Wrath** : Ignite - Increase Ability Power and Attack Damang by 5 while on cooldown. We can be decently liberal with our
  summoner spells, and therefore Ignite should be on cooldown most of
  the game. While 5 AP isn't A LOT, it is really handy, especially in
  the early stages of the game. The added AD is also helpful once we
  purchase a  Runaan's Hurricane.
- **Fury** : +1 / 2 / 3 / 4% Attack Speed This build is focuses heavily on attack speed. There isn't too much more to take at this tier.. if
  you like to spam your summoner spells, you can put a point into
  Summoner's Wrath  instead of maxing this.
- **Sorcery** : +1 / 2 / 3% Cooldown Reduction CDR is pretty nice to keep harassing and dropping mushrooms on the map, however this
  doesn't offer very much CDR. Simply taken because the other choices
  in this tier are less beneficial.
- **Blast** : +0.25 / 0.50 / 0.75 / 1.00 Ability Power per level. Provides a very nice little chunk of AP into late game. Including 
  Rabadon's Deathcap this nets up 23 additional AP!
- **Arcane Knowledge** : +8% Magic Penetration Magic Pen is a very helpful (and hard to come by) stat. It decreases the enemy's
  resistance to all our spells, increasing our damage. This paired with
  Sorcerer's Shoes,  Void Staff, or  Abyssal Scepter lets us do a lot
  more damage to the opponents, especially to tanks.
- **Mental Force** : +2 / 4 / 6 Ability Power Straight up additional ability power is a must take. Increases our early game damage quite a
  bit and is the one of the only AP choices at this tier.
- **Spellsword** : +5% of your Ability Power added to your Auto Attack This mastery was made for Teemo! It is identical to the way  Nashor's
  Tooth works (a key item to this build). Since most of our damage
  comes from our auto attacks in combination with  Toxic Shot, this is
  a must have mastery.
- **Archmage** : +1.25 / 2.50 / 3.75 / 5% Ability Power This is the best option for any ability power champion. Increases our AP by +5%
  which means it gets stronger the more AP you have!
- **Executioner** : +5% Damage to targets below 50% health Pretty self explanatory, you deal 5% more damage if the enemy is below 50%
  health. This is a very nice mastery for Teemo as our poison damage,
  shroom damage, and ignite can all be dealing additional damage while
  we run away laughing from a fight.

*Utility*

- **Summoner's Insight** : Reduces the cooldown of  Flash by 15 seconds Flash is one of the most power escapes in the game, and one that you
  should always be using! Reducing the CD on this spell is very handy
  to escape tight situations.
- **Wanderer** : + 0.66 / 1.33 / 2% movement increase when out of combat Teemo is one of the fastest champions. Increasing his movement
  speed is the most beneficial choices out of both the Utility and
  Defensive Trees.
- **Improved Recall** : Reduces the cast time of   Recall by 1 second This point is most added because the other option is to increase mana
  regen which is mostly useless for Teemo. Ever hid in a bush and
  started Recalling while an enemy starts marching towards you? Its a
  scary place to be, but this can up your chances of survival!
- **Mastermind** : Reduces the cooldown of Summoner Spells by 4 / 7 / 10% Allows us to use both  Flash and  Ignite more frequently which is
  extremely handy.

**Summoner Spells**

*Preferred*

- **Flash** : Provides an escape more beneficial than our  Move Quick as it allows you to jump over walls and out of slows. I ALWAYS take
  this spell regardless of my 2nd choice.
- **Ignite** : Getting an enemy to low health is a pretty easy task, however most people will carry a  Health Potion,  Heal, or have an
  health regen ability. This spell allows your  Toxic Shot to keep
  dwindling down their health without having to worry about them
  recovering.
- **Exhaust** : A nice way to defend yourself against a gank or to focus down an AD carry in a team fight, however with our  Noxious
  Trap the slow isn't as useful as our other spell options.
- **Heal** : If you find yourself being the target of early harass or ganks, take this spell to ensure your survivabiltiy. Also ensure you
  use it in team fights to provide a heal for your entire team!
- **Ghost** : This, in combination with our  Move Quick, will make you so fast that the enemy will be baffled. Can also be utilized to run
  across the entire map in just a few seconds to score a gank or to
  save a turret!
- **Barrier** : An excellent choice for new players or ARAM if you find yourself the focus in a team fight. Just pop this spell and continue
  owning the Field of Justice!

**Items**

*Core Items - AP Teemo*

- **Doran's Blade** While relying on this baby's on-hit HP regen to sustain us, this can be a nice change from the standard below. Adds
  quite a bit to our HP pool and makes our harassment stronger. Also it
  can be fun to watch the enemy stack armour only to find that our late
  game is AP.
- **Boots of Speed** + **Health Potion** x3 A standard starting build. Offers amazing mobility with your boots to escape from ganks or to
  keep up your pokes with  Toxic Shot. Makes up for your low HP with
  health regen with your health potions.
- **Mercury's Treads** Pick these up next if you are against a heavy AP team or you have to deal with CC. I like to play mid so the magic
  resist is really useful, however pick your boots depending on who you
  are up against. If you are taking a lot of auto attack damage get 
  Ninja Tabi instead, or if you are facing no harass and the other team
  is not providing a threat, take  Sorcerer's Shoes for magic pen or 
  Berserker's Greaves for extra attack speed. Always choose your boots
  depending on the makeup of the other team.
- **Nashor's Tooth** I absolutely adore this item! This gives your early/mid game a big boost with the attack speed it offers.  Toxic
  Shot provides on-hit magic damage, so building a more attack speed on
  Teemo is never a bad idea for both AD or AP builds. The cool down
  reduction will also help with getting more shrooms out on the field.
  With the recent change to Nashor's Tooth to include the on-hit
  ability of Malady, this item has become Teemo's most dangerous
  weapon. Nashor's Tooth's on hit damage IS applies to three targets
  when paired with  Runaan's Hurricane.
- **Runaan's Hurricane** This is the focus of the build. The passive of applying on-hit effects (such as  Toxic Shot and  Nashor's Tooth) to
  two additional targets makes you suddenly a very large threat in team
  fights, as well as an amazing farmer. Picking up a Doran's Blade
  first just gives this a little more kick to damage as well as
  providing 15 HP back instead of 5. The reason we rush this item is
  the insane farming potential. We will sacrifice early game damage,
  but its worth it in mid/late game when you can complete a full build
  much faster than anyone else.
- **Rabadon's Deathcap** The icing on the cake. Now that we have built a decent amount of AP, lets give it a massive boost! Most people like
  to take this item first, but as it scales with the amount of AP you
  have, I prefer to take it mid game when you can farm the gold within
  a few minion waves. This item speaks for itself and is a must for any
  champion who focus's AP.
- **Liandry's Torment** While this item does NOT proc from  Toxic Shot, this will give your shrooms a MASSIVE punch as the the ticks will
  whittle down the poor enemy's HP much faster than usual due to the
  additional DoT and slow.
- **Void Staff** The other team has probably realized you are quite the threat and should be building up some magic resistance. Nab this
  beauty to make 35% of their magic resist useless >:) .

Thank you for taking the time to read all I had to say. I really hope that I helped you and best luck in the Fields of Justice!

Comment: This answer doesn't answer his question at all.  He is specifically asking about how to win the Teemo vs Teemo matchup.  Not all of the options on how to build teemo.

Answer (score -2):

CDR wins. Make sure you get 2 blinding darts off while he only gets off 1. If he isn't building CDR, you can win.